# What is the best way to convert a value to boolean in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking for the most commonly used way to get the truthy/falsy value in typescript

I've seen

- `!!value`
- `Boolean(value)`
- For strings: `value !== null && value !== undefined && value !== ''`
- For numbers: `value !== null && value !== undefined && value !== 0`

What is the most standard?

Comment: `!!value` is the simplest and most common

Comment: This is mostly up to preferences. I personally, prefer using `Boolean(value)` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The most common are:

- `!!value`
- `Boolean(value)`

They both work the same and give the same results. When it comes to readability I would choose Boolean if I am working in a team better for a clean code and I think most developers would understand this more. "!!" is less code and faster (to use it).  So yeah in the end it's more of a preference.